# Using --plugin-dir parameter when starting Kibana

Tags: plugins, kibana, kibana-5

I am developing plugins for Kibana 5.2.1 on Windows 10.

I have the following directory structure:

- *KibanaAll*

  - *Kibana* (this is the regular Kibana installation)
  - *Plugins*

    - *MyPlugin1*
    - *MyPlugin2*

To start Kibana with a single plugin, I go to the Kibana directory in a terminal (Windows PowerShell), and use the following command:

```
.\bin\kibana.bat --dev --plugin-path "../plugins/MyPlugin1"
```

This works fine, using the `plugin-path` parameter.

*Note: I was having problems with npm start since it uses the linux script, so I use the bat script directly*

---

Now, I want Kibana to use all my plugins, so I use the `plugin-dir` parameter with the following command

`.\bin\kibana.bat --dev --plugin-dir "../plugins"`

I get this error:

`Error: Unmet requirement "elasticsearch" for plugin "MyPlugin1"`

See the [full error dump here](http://pastebin.com/Wg9M7Hvy). MyPlugin1 is indeed requiring elasticsearch, but I do not get this error when using `plugin-path` parameter.

Am I using the `--plugin-dir` parameter incorrectly? How can I make it work?